# Issue with experimental gradle: The android plugin must be applied to the project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to run some native code with the NDK in Android Studio.
I have followed the steps shown [HERE](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)
to use the experimental Gradle, but obviously it's not all going smoothly.
I'm getting this error: `The android or android-library plugin must be applied to the project` 
Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 22
        buildToolsVersion = "22.0.1"

        android.ndk {
            moduleName = "test"
        }

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.shaperstudio.dartboard"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude = 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
        compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
        apt 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare-compiler:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:1.3'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
    }
```

Any help as to why I'm getting this error would be appreciated

Comment: not familiar with those other plugins, but maybe the 1st line needs to be: ~ apply plugin: 'com.android.application' ?

Comment: That's how it used to be but the experimental plugin requires it to have it the way it is on my example.

Comment: It looks like the error comes from the other two 'apply plugin', but I have no idea why it is so. It worked fine before the change to the experimental gradle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced with this problem to some weeks ago. The com.neenbedankt.android-apt plugin require android or android-library plugin.

I wrote a letter to apt plugin author https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt.

> Hello!
>   Google announced android studio preview 1.3 with jni support few days ago. For this purpose they use plugin com.android.model.application (classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.1.0"). It is not compatible with your plugin. I tried to do my own fork, but I am not good in plugin development. Are you going to support new plugin?

Answer.

> Not in the short term, since the required hooks are still missing and it looks like it would be a rewrite since a lot has changed. You should be able to create a separate module for NDK stuff using the experimental plugin, and another for all other Android stuff using the stable plugin.

I also tried to make my own fork of android-apt, but I am not a gradle guru, and I have not enough time.

So you should create separate module only for NDK (for example to compute something).

Comment: Experienced same problem, but in my case using another module wasn't a solution. So I've created plugin for new experimental android gradle plugin. https://bitbucket.org/pvoid/android-apt-experemental/overview

Comment: "provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'" leads to "Gradle DSL method not found: 'provided()' "

Answer (score 7):

Try to use this plugin

https://bitbucket.org/pvoid/android-apt-experemental/overview

instead of android-apt

Comment: except for "classpath 'org.bitbucket.pvoid:android-apt-experemental:1.0.1'" in dependencies, should I use apply plugin: 'xxxx'   ???

Comment: >> except for "classpath 'org.bitbucket.pvoid:android-apt-experemental:1.0.1'" in dependencies, should I use apply plugin: 'xxxx' ???

No, you shouldn't it is plugging for build script

Comment: >> "provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'" leads to "Gradle DSL method not found: 'provided()' "

There is no "provided" dependency type in new DSL. Read this discussion for solving problem https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-best-define-dependencies-as-provided/6412

Comment: sorry, I guess posted wrong msg and delete it. The error message is "Gradle DSL method not found: 'apt()"

Comment: My bad, documentation about configuration miss plugin apply line. You have to add line "apply plugin: 'org.bitbucket.pvoid.android-apt'" inside your app build.gradle file

Comment: thx, "apt()" works. "provided()" still NOT work, I just do not know the exact grammar in experimental-gradle to include "configurations { provided }", it would be great if u can help me out!   My build.gradle pasted in https://gist.github.com/e-snail/d82e2284e00cfc21400adf46530ff8b1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109543/discussion-between-henry-pootle-and-roff).