# How to use Android NDK and Fabric at the same time?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, twitter-fabric

I have a Crashlytics-enabled app (which is now part of Twitter's Fabric) and I need to add some JNI functionality using the Android NDK.

I've switched to experimental gradle as Android Studio prompted me that way:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

When I've applied the necessary changes and tried to sync, I've got the error:

`Crashlytics was applied to a project without an Android plugin. Please make sure the Crashlytics plugin is applied after the appropriate Android plugin for your project.`

I've googled the error and found out that it's a problem between Fabric and experimental gradle, and Fabric team doesn't really seem to care about fixing it any time soon: https://twittercommunity.com/t/gradle-experiental-support/53441.

I've stumbled upon [Issue with experimental gradle: The android plugin must be applied to the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001570/issue-with-experimental-gradle-the-android-plugin-must-be-applied-to-the-projec) but I have no idea what to do there, and I'm not sure if it's the right way to go?

How can I use Android NDK *and* Fabric in my project?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @Charx revert back to non-experiemental gradle. the docs are misleading that it won't work. because it actually *does* work with the old gradle.

Answer (score 2):

So gradle-experimental and Fabric don't mix.

**Solution:**

1) update to latest Android Studio 2.3.1

2) follow this tutorial to drop gradle experimental: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

What I did was create a new temporary project with C++ support enabled and added a blank activity.

Then I opened my current project and the temporary project and copied the necessary changes into my own project.

After I was done (about 1 hour of work) I was able to build my C code into a library, load the library into my project, and make the JNI calls.